# msxml6.dll error '80070005' Access is denied. when opening xml document

Tags: xml, asp-classic, iis-7, server

In the course of moving a classic asp website to a new server, I have found that the new server will not open a xml document. When tried, I get the error above. The code is known to work, so I don't think it would be the issue, but here is how I load the document:

```
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0") 
objXMLDoc.async = False
objXMLDoc.load "\\WServer\c\inetpub\ItemTrack\Content\Helper\Standard.xml"
```

The error is occuring on the objXMLDoc.load line. The most common causes for this were the server not having permission to open the file and the access across domain security setting not being correct. I have ensured that the server does indeed have permissions with the file and then some. Currently the IIS_IUSRS group, Everyone group, and Server Users group all have full permissions. Although I have not changed the access across domain setting, as I do not have permission to do so, when I compared this server's settings with the previous server that was able to access the file, the settings appear identical. For this reason, I don't think that this would cause the error that I am having. I am currently trying to have someone change it for safety's sake, but I would like to try and explore other avenues in the mean time.

Given that this is a new server, could there be some IIS setting that needs to be changed to allow this to work (IIS 7 by the way)? Is there some other probable cause for this error?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your IUSR account has access to where the xml file resides

Comment: As i said in my post, the IIS_IUSR group has full permissions to the file. Or am I misunderstanding and there is some other facet of IUSR that needs permission?